# How can I fix Xorg startup problem?

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, drivers, kde

I am using Arch Linux and I was using awesome wm and everything worked perfectly. I installed plasma-meta package to try KDE 5 so after I rebooted the system X does not start. Lightdm, sddm fails and also `startx` is not working. I have created [this thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1569281#p1569281) in Arch Linux forums.

I searched a bit what does this mean and it should be related to full root partition so,

```
df -H

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail     Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb2       4G   29M   3.8G      1%        /
dev             1.8G     0  1.8G          0%       /dev
run             1.9G   8.4M  1.8G       1%       /run
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G         0%       /dev/shm
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G         0%       /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1       20G  5G  14G       27%     /var
/dev/sda6       888G 828G  16G    99%     /data
/dev/sda5       20G  19G  278M     99%     /home
/dev/sda4       9.8G 221M  9G     3%     /tmp
tmpfs           362M     0  362M   0% /run/user/1000
```

I have erased some things in /home so now I have 78% use but no success.

Also, xorg.conf file

```
xorg.conf

Section "ServerLayout"

    #InputDevice                    "Keyboard"  "CoreKeyboard"
    Identifier     "Layout"
    Screen      0  "0-Primary" 0 0
    Screen         "1-Secondary" LeftOf "0-Primary"
EndSection

Section "Files"
    ModulePath   "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
    XkbDir      "usr/share/X11/xkb"
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load  "extmod"
    Load  "glx"
    Load  "dri"
    Load  "dri2"
    Load  "dbe"
    Load  "record"
#   Load  "xtrap"
    Load  "type1"
    Load  "freetype"
EndSection

Section "ServerFlags"
    Option      "DontZap" "on"
    Option      "BlankTime" "20"
    Option      "StandbyTime" "20"
    Option      "Xinerama" "off"
    Option      "AIGLX" "on"
    Option      "DRI2" "on"
    Option      "GlxVisuals" "all"
    Option      "AutoAddDevices" "on"
    Option      "AutoEnableDevices" "on"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "0-CRT2"
    VendorName   "LG"
    HorizSync    30.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh  56.0 - 75.0
    Option      "DPMS" "on"
    Option      "Primary" "on"
    Option      "PreferredMode" "1920x1080"
    Option      "Position" "0 0"
    Option      "RightOf" "1-Secondary"
    Option      "Enable" "on"
    Option      "TargetRefresh" "60"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "1-CRT1"
    VendorName   "Belinea"
    HorizSync    31.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh  56.0 - 75.0
    Option      "DPMS" "on"
    Option      "Primary" "on"
    Option      "PreferredMode" "1280x1024"
    Option      "Position" "-1920 0"
    Option      "LeftOf" "0-Primary"
    Option      "Enable" "on"
    Option      "TargetRefresh" "60"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "HD 4890"
    Driver      "fglrx"
    Option      "OpenGLOverlay" "1"
    Option      "AccelMethod" "EXA"
    Option      "AGPMode" "on"
    Option      "AGPFastWrite" "on"
    Option      "ColorTiling" "on"
    Option      "EnablePageFlip" "on"
    BusID       "PCI:2:00:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "HD 4200"
    Driver      "fglrx"
    Option      "OpenGLOverlay" "1"
    Option      "AccelMethod" "EXA"
    Option      "AGPMode" "on"
    Option      "AGPFastWrite" "on"
    Option      "ColorTiling" "on"
    Option      "EnablePageFlip" "on"
    BusID       "PCI:1:05:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "0-Primary"
    Device     "HD 4890"
    Monitor "0-CRT2"
    DefaultDepth     24
    Option      "NoMTRR" "off"
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
        Modes    "1920x1080"
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "1-Secondary"
    Device     "HD 4200"
    Monitor "1-CRT1"
    DefaultDepth     24
    Option      "NoMTRR" "off"
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
        Modes    "1280x1024"
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "DRI"
                                   # May help enable direct rendering.
    Mode         0666
EndSection

Section "Extensions"
    Option      "Composite" "Enable"
EndSection
```

This the xorg log file

[Xorg Log file](https://pastee.org/4pv3a)

Comment: It might be useful to get the whole /var/log/Xorg.0.log.

Comment: Yes, but I do not know how to copy it from the computer with the problem, X is not working. I am posting this from another pc.

Comment: Press Alt+Shift+2 to switch to a shell session and log in using your credentials, then you can use Linux commands.

Comment: @HamzaAbbad Yes but I cannot open a browser to post log content :)

Comment: But you can insert a flash drive and mount it then copy that file to it.

Comment: @HamzaAbbad Mounting flash drive was easier than i thought, Thanks

Comment: Why are only 29MB of your root partition used? And why does /dev/sda1 have 14GT (?) available?

Comment: I have an SSD and a hard drive. When I started configuring Arch I gathered information on how to improve SSD performance. I do not remember what I did exactly. Is there any problem with root partition not being used? Also, 14 G not 14GT, sorry for that